Erro ao tentar realizar pagamento pela API Mercado Pago com split
Estou tentando criar um pagamento via API com o recurso de split.
Só que quando tento criar o pagamento eu recebo o seguinte erro:  [400]: GET to API MARKETPLACE fail
Abaixo são os dados enviados na requisição:
[
    'payment_method_id' => "pix",
    'transaction_amount' => 'valor',
    'description' => 'descricao',
    'payer' => 'cliente',
    'marketplace' => 'access_token_da_loja',
    'application_fee' => 'valor_referente_a_loja',
]

O token utilizado na requisição é o do vendedor, que foi gerado com sucesso pelo oAuth.
Se tiro o campo marketplace o erro é o segiunte: [400]: You cannot use application_fee with this payment.
Alguém que já passou por esse erro pode dar uma ajuda?

Uma pergunta similar já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
